# Filter for previous time periods in views

Tags: 8, views

I'm trying to set up Grouped filters for `Content revision: Changed` in a view. I want the filter to work for Today, Yesterday, Last week, Last month, and Last year. The grouped filters makes that simple enough, and it looks like this:

[image]

But all the filters are not filtering correctly.

For the Today filter, this will work.

[image]

But When I try to use an `Is between` operator for any previous dates, I get an error like this

[image]

How do I filter for previous time periods in views?

---

The Today filter works with `Is greater than or equal to` `today midnight`. It's the `Is between` parameters that the view won't accept.

The existing `Today` filter query adds

```
 AND ((node_field_revision.changed >= 1597759242-68400))
```

to the query, which converts to

```
GMT: Tuesday, August 18, 2020 2:00:42 PM - 19 hours.
```

Setting the Yesterday filter with `Is less than or equal` to `yesterday` adds

```
AND ((node_field_revision.changed <= 1597759395-154800))
```

to the query, which converts to

```
GMT: Tuesday, August 18, 2020 2:03:15 PM - 43 hours
```

which means the filter will show values from yesterday and today. That's not a `yesterday` filter.

So `Is between` is the way to go, but any values I try, including yours @Yuseferi, aren't accepted in the UI and so can't adjust to the query accordingly. If the view would accept an `Is between` operator, the query would add something like this:

```
AND ((node_field_revision.changed <= 1597759956-(1597723200-1597636800))
```

Where

```
Now: 1597759956
Today: 1597723200
Yesterday: 1597636800
```

That would be a yesterday query, which Drupal could then adjust for GMT.

Comment: Did you try reversing the inputs for yesterday? Also, those aren't offsets. You might need "-2 day" for the first and "-1 day" for the second

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

data between `today 1 sec ago` and `yesterday`